# Determining coordinates of corners of raster layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, extents

How can we determine the coordinates of the corners of the raster layer?

The image opens function QgsRasterLayer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just [found](http://schwehr.org/blog/archives/2012-06.html) the following snippet, it might be what you are looking for:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

bag = gdal.Open('F00574_MB_2m_MLLW_2of3.bag')  # replace it with your file
                                               # raster is projected
bag_gtrn = bag.GetGeoTransform()
bag_proj = bag.GetProjectionRef()
bag_srs = osr.SpatialReference(bag_proj)
geo_srs =bag_srs.CloneGeogCS()                 # new srs obj to go from x,y -> φ,λ
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation( bag_srs, geo_srs)

bag_bbox_cells = (
    (0., 0.),
    (0, bag.RasterYSize),
    (bag.RasterXSize, bag.RasterYSize),
    (bag.RasterXSize, 0),
  )

geo_pts = []
for x, y in bag_bbox_cells:
    x2 = bag_gtrn[0] + bag_gtrn[1] * x + bag_gtrn[2] * y
    y2 = bag_gtrn[3] + bag_gtrn[4] * x + bag_gtrn[5] * y
    geo_pt = transform.TransformPoint(x2, y2)[:2]
    geo_pts.append(geo_pt)
    print x, y, '->', x2, y2, '->', geo_pt
```

The results of this code are:

```
# Pixel Coord ->     Proj Coords    ->    (φ,λ) coords
0.0 0.0       -> 369179.0 4775259.0 -> (-70.608087740520943, 43.118768822635147)                                
0.0 1083      -> 369179.0 4773093.0 -> (-70.607577288471774, 43.099271863165256)                               
1841 1083     -> 372861.0 4773093.0 -> (-70.56234820699548, 43.099898472783011)                               
1841 0.0      -> 372861.0 4775259.0 -> (-70.562844311963829, 43.119395856927362)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I do not know a variable in Python, I use the command dir(variable) to examine the options available in the class from which it is derived

and thus in this case:

In QGIS 1.8

```
rlayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
ext =rlayer.extent()
dir(ext)
 [...,'asPolygon', 'asWktCoordinates', 'center', ...,'height',...,'width', 'xMaximum', 'xMinimum',
 'yMaximum', 'yMinimum']
```

so I try what seems interesting:

```
ext.asPolygon()
Qt4.QtCore.QString(u'162012.44098000 158167.46835000, 162012.44098000 168174.76215000, 178013.37218000 168174.76215000, 178013.37218000 158167.46835000, 162012.44098000 158167.46835000')
```

gives you the coordinates of the corners of the raster layer

In QGIS master

```
ext =rlayer.extent()
dir(ext)
[...,'.asPolygon', 'asWktCoordinates', 'asWktPolygon', 'center',...height', ..., 'width',...,
'xMaximum', 'xMinimum', 'yMaximum', 'yMinimum']
```

same approach

```
l.asWktPolygon()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'POLYGON((162012.4409800000139512 158167.468349999981001, 178013.3721800000057556 158167.468349999981001, 178013.3721800000057556 168174.7621499999950174, 162012.4409800000139512 168174.7621499999950174, 162012.4409800000139512 158167.468349999981001))')
# or
l.asPolygon()
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'162012.44098000 158167.46835000, 162012.44098000 168174.76215000, 178013.37218000 168174.76215000, 178013.37218000 158167.46835000, 162012.44098000 158167.46835000')
```

gives you the coordinates of the corners of the raster layer and you can use the other elements

```
l.xMinimum(),l.yMinimum(),l.xMaximum(), l.yMaximum()
(162012.44098000001, 158167.46834999998, 178013.37218000001, 168174.76215)
l.center()
(170013,163171)
```

It may take time but it allows you to learn the class