# is it possible to open a geotiff file in python without using gdal?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, shapely, well-known-text

Trying to get [gdal](http://www.gdal.org/) and whichever associated python bindings installed with the oldish OS my company uses is extremely painful, especially so in ci/cd and testing situations. I keep coming across libraries such as [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) or [fiona](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona), but it seems like everything has this [whole mess of dependencies](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona#installation), some of which the OS doesn't have.

It's especially frustrating because what I'm doing isn't complex..
I have a geotiff file that's easy to `gdal.open(..)`. I basically just need a footprint. If I could get to WKT or any other format but geotiff I can easily do what I need to with shapely/numpy/etc. What I need isn't too far off from what's found in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57837), I just need to do it without gdal.

Said another way, there is some GEO data in a geotiff, how can I get the geometry or footprint from it in python without using gdal?

Comment: Define *footprint*, are you after the extent of the raster or the part that isn't NoData? Are you able to gdal.open? What OS are you using? WKT isn't a raster format, it's a vector format.

Comment: Not an answer, since it doesn't answer your *actual* question... Suggest you use `conda` in your ci/cd/testing toolchain.  It's simple to automate building a reproducible conda env, run tests and build & deploy releases. And it makes it easy to install GDAL on oldish OSs.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I believe "extent" is the correct term. Does it make sense to say I'd like the extent in a usable vector format? I can gdal.open on my laptop.

Comment: @Luke unfortunately I don't own the toolchain.. I'm working with python virtualenvs.

Comment: Yes that does make sense, it could have gone either way depending on what you want them for. If you can ds=gdal.Open(r'c:\path\to\your\raster.ext') then gt=ds.GetGeoTransform() http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html  cols = ds.RasterXSize
rows = ds.RasterYSize XMin=gt[0], YMax=gt[3], XMax=gt[0]+(gt[1]*cols),YMin=gt[3]+(gt[5]*rows) provided the raster isn't rotated (gt[2] == 0 and gt[4] == 0) from here you should be able to create 5 points in a gdal.Geometry http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html and export as WKT.

Comment: You can also use `pytiff` http://pytiff.readthedocs.io/en/master/  `pip install pytiff`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to read the TIFF metadata tags using the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/) library. This may be easier to set up than GDAL (although it still has numpy as a dependency)

I don't seem to be able to open all geotiffs, and some larger geotiffs (1 Gb or more) trip the "decompression bomb" check.

For more information on what the tags mean, see [this spec](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff2.6.html).

————

```
(venv) pip freeze
numpy==1.14.1
Pillow==5.0.0
```

example:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("/Users/steven/infoviz/longyearbyen/filled.tif")
print("Dimensions : {}".format(im.size))
for id in im.tag:
    print("{} : {}".format(id, im.tag[id]))
```

Here’s some example data. From this example I can see the top left corner in tag 33922 (the geotransform), and the pixel size in 33550. You should be able to work out the extent from that?

```
Dimensions : (3123, 2664)
256 : (3123,)
257 : (2664,)
258 : (32,)
259 : (1,)
33922 : (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 507065.54896554863, 8690337.593779845, 0.0) 
42113 : ('-99999',)
262 : (1,)
33550 : (4.999591964799991, 4.999591964799715, 0.0)
273 : 
— snip —
284 : (1,)
34735 : (1, 1, 0, 8, 1024, 0, 1, 1, 1025, 0, 1, 1, 1026, 34737, 22, 0, 2049, 34737, 7, 22, 2054, 0, 1,     9102, 2062, 34736, 3, 0, 3072, 0, 1, 25833, 3076, 0, 1, 9001)
34736 : (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
34737 : ('ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N|ETRS89|',)
```

Comment: This is interesting! I am going to play with it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: To open larger TIFs, add `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None` after importing `Image`. Of course now you are open to decompression bombs...

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too. To solve this, I have started the [geotiff python package](https://pypi.org/project/geotiff/).

It's a fairly new project and I discuss the roadmap [here](https://kipcrossing.github.io/2021-01-04-geotiff-python-package/)